# Cosa significa "ciancicare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Diamante tiene il passaporto fra i denti – col consenso di suo padre all’espatrio stampigliato accanto ai suoi connotati. È talmente indaffarato a sgomitare che non sta a chiedersi come mai Vita non **ciancica** piú fra le labbra lo scontrino giallo.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "Vita non ciancica piú fra le labbra lo scontrino giallo" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "ciancicare" in parecchi dizionari, ma le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ciancicare nel dialetto romano significa masticare.

Treccani riporta per [ciancicare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciancicare/):

> **ciancicare** v. intr. e tr. [der. di *cianciare*] (*io ciàncico, tu
> ciàncichi,* ecc.; come intr., aus. *avere*). – 1. Pronunciare male e a
> stento le parole, balbettare. 2. Biascicare, masticare lentamente. 3.
> Lavorare con lentezza e in modo impacciato, far male un lavoro. 4.
> region. a. Sgualcire; come intr. pron., sgualcirsi: i*l vestito si è
> tutto ciancicato.* b. Brancicare, cincischiare. ◆ Part. pass.
> ciancicato, anche come agg., sgualcito: u*na gonna tutta ciancicata*.

Direi che l’accezione più adatta sia la 2, sebbene nella fattispecie mi fa venire in mente che Vita stia tenendo lo scontrino fra le labbra e lo stia succhiando come fanno i neonati o i bimbi piccoli.

Comment: Mmmm... Non avevo pensato che potesse significare "masticare". In realtà, il dialetto di Diamante e Vita è il [minturnese](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minturno).

Comment: Essendo un comune in provincia di Latina, nel Lazio penso che alcune espressioni e parole siano mutuate dal dialetto romano.

Comment: Sì, infatti Wikipedia afferma che è un dialetto che deriva dalla lingua napoletana, ma ha anche elementi dal ciociaro e dal romanesco. Dobbiamo etichettare la domanda con la tag "regional"?

Comment: Direi che sarebbe appropriato, sebbene la voce sia riportata anche da Treccani

Comment: Direi di no, @Charo: moltissime parole italiane sono nate in una qualche regione (diversa dalla Toscana, diciamo). Ma una volta che sono entrate a pieno titolo nell'italiano standard non le considererei più “regionali” (se non ci riferiamo a usi diversi dallo standard etc.).

Comment: @DaG: Ma questo vocabolo con questo significato si usa in tutta Italia? Per esempio, nel [*Diccionari de la llengua catalana* de l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans](http://mdlc.iec.cat/results.asp?txtEntrada=fraula&operEntrada=0) appare il termine "fraula" col significato di "maduixa", che in italiano sarebbe "fragola". Ma prova a chiedere in una qualsiasi gelateria di Barcellona "un gelat de fraula", cioè, un gelato di fragola. Ti posso assicurare che non ti capiscono in nessuna perché "fraula" è un vocabolo che si usa, che io sappia, soltanto a Maiorca. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Quindi io direi che si tratta di vocabolario regionale.

Comment: Del catalano e delle sue norme lessicografiche non so niente, ma per “ciancicare” il Treccani, il De Mauro, il Devoto-Oli e lo Zingarelli attribuiscono la marca “regionale” solo al senso “sgualcire” (“Questa camicia è tutta ciancicata”). Ne deduco che negli altri significati sia un termine italiano tout court. Detto altrimenti: in base a cosa decideremmo che sia regionale?

Comment: @DaG: Non mi ero accorta (o avevo dimenticato) che i dizionari italiani usano la marca "regionale" (purtroppo, i dizionari del mio paese non sono tanto buoni come quelli italiani). Quindi, hai ragione!

Comment: Fatto interessante @Charo: se ti interessa vedere un utilizzo di "ciancicare" in un film ti consiglio di cercare il film con Jim Carrey "Ace Ventura: l'Acchiappanimali (Pet Detective)". Nella scena in cui si infiltra alla festa per cercare il delfino, mentre mangia, usa proprio "ciancicare" nella seconda accezione! Inoltre è un film fatalmente divertente!

Comment: @Easymode44: Cioè, il doppiaggio all'italiano di questo film?

Comment: @Charo sí! Eccolo! https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7MEoc__sMqY

Comment: @Easymode44: Interessante... Quindi Vita faceva una cosa simile a quello che si vede nel video con lo scontrino fra le labbra.